# Pattern.matcher in java 8 does not match section sign §

Tags: regex, java-8

I have this following code snippet :

```
private static final Pattern ESCAPER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\p{P}\\s]*");

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String unaccentedText = "Aa123 \\/*-+.=+:/;.,?u%µ£$*^¨-)ac!e§('\"e&€#²³~´][{^";
    System.out.println(ESCAPER_PATTERN.matcher(unaccentedText).replaceAll(""));         
}
```

When I execute this with JDK 7 the output I get is:

```
Aa123 \/*-.:/;.,?u%*-)ac!e('"e&#][{
```

When I execute the same with JDK 8 the output I get is:

```
Aa123 \/*-.:/;.,?u%*-)ac!e§('"e&#][{
```

Notice that the section sign § is not removed with JDK 8.

Please let me know the regex to be used in case of JDK 8 to match the section sign as well - and also the reason for this difference in behaviour between jdks.

Comment: I don't see `\p{P}` in the [Java 8 documentation for `Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) - what is that supposed to match?

Comment: @SeanBright: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#ucc and look for "General category" constants in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

Comment: @nhahtdh - I'm a bit thick and I'm not seeing just "P" anywhere. I'll take your word for it that if I read it more closely I would understand :-)

Comment: @SeanBright: Ah, that doesn't seem to be clearly mentioned. `P` encompasses all categories whose shorthand started with `P` (Punctuation).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Unicode moved your cheese

The character `U+00A7 SECTION SIGN` was changed from category So (Symbol, Other) to category Po (Punctuation, Other) in [Unicode 6.1.0](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/tr44-10.html#Unicode_6.1.0):

> - UnicodeData.txt
>
>   - U+00A7, U+00B6, U+0F14, U+1360, and U+10102 were changed from gc=So to gc=Po.

Since Java uses [Unicode 6.0.0](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) in version 7, and updates to [Unicode 6.2.0](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) in version 8, it explains the difference in the result. As `§` now belongs Punctuation category, it is matched by `\p{P}` in Java 8.

#### Wrong solution

Since regular punctuations like `!`, `#`, `"`, ... also belong to Po category, we can't really remove this subcategory.

The next obvious solution is to use character set intersection to remove the unwanted character:

```
"[^a-zA-Z0-9\\p{P}\\s&&[^\u00a7]]"
```

... but **wait a minute**, there is [a bug in Java with negated character class inside negated character class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934168/bug-in-double-negation-of-regex-character-classes/21961347#21961347), the regex above compiles to:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\p{P}\s&&[^§]]
Start. Start unanchored match (minLength=1)
Pattern.intersection. S ∩ T:
  Pattern.setDifference. S ∖ T:
    Pattern.setDifference. S ∖ T:
      Pattern.setDifference. S ∖ T:
        Pattern.setDifference. S ∖ T:
          CharProperty.complement. S̄:
            Pattern.rangeFor. U+0061 <= codePoint <= U+007A.
          Pattern.rangeFor. U+0041 <= codePoint <= U+005A.
        Pattern.rangeFor. U+0030 <= codePoint <= U+0039.
      DEBUG charProp: java.util.regex.Pattern$Category
    Ctype. POSIX (US-ASCII): SPACE
  CharProperty.complement. S̄:
    BitClass. Match any of these 1 character(s):
      §
java.util.regex.Pattern$LastNode
Node. Accept match
```

... which resolves to `[^a-zA-Z0-9\p{P}\s]` intersect with `[^§]`, instead of not (`[a-zA-Z0-9\p{P}\s]` intersect with `[^§]`).

#### Correct solution

To workaround the bug above, the working solution is:

```
"[[^a-zA-Z0-9\\p{P}\\s]\u00a7]"
```

which compiles to:

```
[[^a-zA-Z0-9\p{P}\s]§]
Start. Start unanchored match (minLength=1)
Pattern.union. S ∪ T:
  Pattern.setDifference. S ∖ T:
    Pattern.setDifference. S ∖ T:
      Pattern.setDifference. S ∖ T:
        Pattern.setDifference. S ∖ T:
          CharProperty.complement. S̄:
            Pattern.rangeFor. U+0061 <= codePoint <= U+007A.
          Pattern.rangeFor. U+0041 <= codePoint <= U+005A.
        Pattern.rangeFor. U+0030 <= codePoint <= U+0039.
      DEBUG charProp: java.util.regex.Pattern$Category
    Ctype. POSIX (US-ASCII): SPACE
  BitClass. Match any of these 1 character(s):
    §
java.util.regex.Pattern$LastNode
Node. Accept match
```

The `§` is correctly included in the character class this time, so the sign will be removed.

*Note that I have removed the quantifier for demonstration purpose. Please add the quantifier back to the character class in your code, preferably **one or more** `+` quantifier, instead of **zero or more** quantifier as used in the question.*